# Creating a third array from smallest integers in two other arrays using C

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int array1[]={ 1, 5 ,23, 18};

int array2[]={ 14,2, 3, 1};

int array3[]; /* Ideal Output of program would be array3[]= {1,2,3,1}  */

int a=0;

for (a=0; a<5; ++a)

{if (array1[a]<array2[a])
    {array3[a]=array1[a]};

else if(array1[a]>=array2[a])
    {array3[a]=array2[a]};

    printf("%d", array3[a])

}    
return=0
}
```

I want to create and print an array which takes the smallest integer from two other arrays. In this example I want to compare 1 to 14 and put 1 into array3[0].

I would also like to print array3

Thanks for any help

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. You have semicolons in the wrong places and are missing them in others. Please submit a working code example and we can help you out!

Comment: Your `for` condition should be `a<4`. You don't need the second `if` part after the else since that's the only possibility if the first `if` condition is false. Remove the `=` from your return statement. And you don't need the semicolons after the closing braces.

Answer (score 3):

Formatting the code properly makes the errors apparent:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int array1[]={  1,  5, 23, 18};

    int array2[]={ 14,  2,  3,  1};

    int array3[]; // Error 1: No size specified

    int a=0;

    for (a=0; a<5; ++a) // Error 2: indexing past the end of the arrays

    {
         if (array1[a]<array2[a])
         {
             array3[a]=array1[a]
         };                      // Error 3: Misplaced semicolon #1
         else if(array1[a]>=array2[a]) // Bug opportunity: unnecessary if
         {
             array3[a]=array2[a]
         };                      // Error 4: Misplaced semicolon #2

         printf("%d", array3[a]) // Error 5: Missing semicolon

    }    
    return=0 // Errors 6/7: '=' and no ';' 
}
```

C compilers don't care about whitespace, but c programmers do, and this is why. Cramming statements together in a small space makes it more difficult to catch important details like these.

Answer (score 2):

This would do it :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifndef min
    #define min(a,b) ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))
#endif

int main() {

    int array1[]={1, 5 ,23, 18};
    int array2[]={14, 2, 3, 1};

    //iterator
    int i=0;

    //Takes the length of the shortest array
    int len=min(sizeof(array1)/sizeof(array1[0]),sizeof(array2)/sizeof(array2[0]));

    //initialize third array to shortest length
    int array3[len];

    printf("array3 = {");

    for (i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        array3[i] = min(array1[i], array2[i]);
        if(i != 0)
        {
            printf(", ");
        }
        printf("%d", array3[i]);

    }
    printf("}"); 
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
array3 = {1, 2, 3, 1}
```

Comment: Macros are evil / awesome.

Comment: You could easily replace the macro with a function here ^^

Comment: Not without malloc. Sizes of arrays on the stack have to be compile-time constants.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your program would essentially work, except for the printout part, where you probably want a comma inside the quotes after the "%d".

However, you don't need to duplicate your "if" condition. You could use array3[a]==(array1[a]

The way you have your "if" statements arranged is not incorrect but it is redundant. Once you have determined that (array1[a]=array2[a]).

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
main() {

int array1[]={ 1, 5 ,23, 18};

int array2[]={ 14,2, 3, 1};

int array3[3]; /* array of size 4, this is where you will store your lowest numbers  */

int a=0; //counter

for (a=0; a<4; ++a)
{
if (array1[a]<array2[a])//checks to see which number is the lowest between the to arrays
{

     array3[a]=array1[a];

}
else
{

   array3[a] = array2[a]; 

 }  
}

for(a=0;a<4;a++)//loop for printing the array3[3];
{
 printf("%d, ", array3[a]);     
}   
 system("pause");//used to pause the program until a key is pressed
}
```

> Okay there we go I fixed it :) hope it helps you n_n if you have any question feel free to ask again , just compile it and run it.